# write to external storage and send e-mail?

Tags: android

i have to make an application in which first i have to create a text file from the data user has entered in the UI and then send the text file as an attachment in an email. For this i will have to write data to the external directory and then pass the URI to the Intent so that the email client in the phone can read it.

i am not sure how would i:

1. write data to the external storage.

2.Pass the URI of the file created to the Intent so that i can attach it to the email.

I have seen several examples of how to send email attachments.. but none fit my requirements hence as a last resort i am posting this question.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Please try to develop your own solution based on the answers to the numerous existing questions on this topic and the developer docs, and then post a question of your own if you get stuck at a specific point where something isn't working as expected.

Comment: Could you give those links, and explain what about them doesn't fit your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Both questions have been answered here many times.

External storage:

- [How can i Use External Storage in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598445/how-can-i-use-external-storage-in-android)
- [How should I refer to "external storage" in the UI on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215265/how-should-i-refer-to-external-storage-in-the-ui-on-android)

Attach a file to an email:

- [Trying to attach a file from SD Card to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email)
- [Android:Attach file with email from device memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918235/androidattach-file-with-email-from-device-memory)

I honestly cannot figure out what is so specific about your requirements. It looks like a pretty standard task to me...

Comment: the Gmail or any other email client will not be able to access if i store the file inside my application....i have to store it in public..somewhere in the external storage....so that other applications can access my data.

Comment: @user that is correct. I forgot about that detail :/ Anyway, what is the part you're stuck in?

Comment: first there are several public directories...like Environment.DOWNLOADS, MUSIC..where should i put my file? Also once i have put it in that directory how do pass it to the Intent which i am calling to send email?

Comment: You can create any folder you want in there. None of the standard ones seem suitable for a text file, so you can create a folder with your app name and put it inside it. If you're going to delete the file as soon as it is sent, then a tmp folder would not be a bad idea. If you're making a Froyo app, check this option: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29

Comment: For the second question, the two links I posted for emails show how to pass the file path to the email intent.